# How to avoid having pith on dried orange peels

Tags: peeling, oranges, peel, dried-fruit

I am trying to prepare some dried orange peel for a [Mexican chocolate bread recipe](https://www.bigoven.com/recipe/mexican-chocolate-bread-for-machine/136768). From [what I've read](https://www.mygourmetconnection.com/make-your-own-dried-orange-peel/), the first step is cutting thin strips of outer peel off an orange without getting any pith. I lack the dexterity to yield a paring knife so I used a vegetable grater. Most of the pieces contain some pith:

[image: slices of orange peel in a glass bowl]

Is the amount of pith shown negligible, or should I use scissors to snip off and keep the portions without it? Is there a better way to get pith-free orange peels? Can I substitute dried zest? (I have a zester that gets peel without pith.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try gently scraping with a spoon or non-serrated knife, if you want to remove more pith.  However, that looks pretty good to me. Your recipe for drying has you finely chopping the peel.  So, I would say that zest would be just fine as well.